# How can I send emails in the background on a WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, email, cron

I a using WishList Member on my wordpress website.

I have created a custom form.

Once users enter their data an email confirmation is sent for them to confirm their email and admin is notified that a user has registered.

These emails are sent slowly so the form submission freezes.

How can I set this up so these emails get put into a cron job so they are sent in the background at a later date?

Thanks

Mitchell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try `wp-mail-smtp` plugin instead?

URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

I recommend you should try this plugin first.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @KyleNeedham Thanks for your suggestion. I will take care about this.